What does a solvable Hamiltonian model mean?
I have recently been reading about simulating the dynamics of many body Hamiltonians by means of quantum computers and I am a bit confused about some terminology. I understand that if you are able to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an specific Hamiltonian, then its ground state and dynamics are given by those. Thus, I understand that a model is solvable if one is able to diagonalize it by some method. However, some times the discussions on those are not very precise or they restrict to finding the ground state (which is nice by itself, but it would not describe the whole dynamics as far as I understand). Thus, am I right in understanding that a model is solvable if the exact diagonalization is known?
Furthermore, I was wondering if there are Hamiltonians for which the energies (eigenvalues) can be effectively computed, but not the eigenstates. I mean if you know the eigenvalues of a huge Hamiltonian (imagine $100$ qubits) but you require to solve the $H|\psi\rangle=\lambda|\psi\rangle$ equation, then it is cannot be computed, in a reasonable amount of time ($2^{100}$ equations). Is this reasonable? If so, what could be an example to this case?
Finally, I did read that the Bethe ansatz does solve (in my notion of solvable, i.e. exactly diagonalize) some Ising and Heisenberg chain Hamiltonians in 1D. However, I did not find any clear classification on which of those could be solved. For example, I found in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.0653, that the transverse field Ising model is exactly solvable in 1D, but not if there is an additional longitudinal field. Thus, are there any known references on which 1D models are exactly solvable? Or whose eigenvalues are known but not their eigenvectors? I also ask this because is somehow counterintuitive for me to see that the transverse field Ising models is solved in 1D and then find quantum computing people simulating it by means of quantum computers. I know that 2D models are much more complex, that's why I am asking this regarding 1D models.

If you are able to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an specific Hamiltonian, then its energy levels and dynamics are given by those.
The lowest eigenvalue, that is the ground state, is often the most interesting since it represents the minimum energy configuration of a quantum system. Many physical phenomena and processes, especially at low temperatures, are dominated by the behavior of the system in this ground state.
There are many systems where eigenvalues are quite easy to solve, but solving eigenstates is not. This is due to the fact that while calculating eigenvalues often involves finding solutions to certain characteristic equations, computing eigenstates requires solving more complex differential equations or understanding the system's full quantum behavior.
The distinction between solvable and non-solvable models often depends on the symmetries of the system and the interactions involved.
It is a good idea in quantum computing to use models that have a known solutions. Quantum Computers have errors, one can learn by studying a known system etc.
An article you gave is a good starting point to look after references. It could be that one need to search research to find out a list of known solutions.

Thank you for your answer. I do agree with the fact that it is a good idea to use Hamiltonians with known solutions to test methods (e.g. mitigation). I meant more to simulate 1D Hamiltonians that are hard (if there are). Regarding your comment "There are many systems where eigenvalues are quite easy to solve, but solving eigenstates is not.", could you give some examples or references on them?

Example where eigenvalues are easy to solve (and eigenstates are not): transverse field Ising model in 1D with Jordan-Wigner transformation. Hard problem in 1D: transverse field spin glass.

Thank you for those. Are those hard with or without periodic boundary conditions in 1D? Also, the transverse field Ising model in 1D, I understand that with the JW transformation you can get the eigenvalues but not eigenvectors? This is actually one of the reasons for doing this question, see in the reference I provided (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.0653) how they call this model as "exactly solvable", I think they even compute the ground state. Thus, I from your answer, this sould not be "exactly solvable", however, they do say so. Could you clarify this?

"they call this model as "exactly solvable"" Onsager’s solution works when boundary conditions are periodic. But yes as far as I know when boundary conditions are something else there is no exact solution. No exct solution but some progress towards it. When problem becomes hard typically physicists mumble something unheardable and argue about infinities ;)

As far as I have read, Onsager's solution is for the case where there is no magnetic field, so it would not include the transverse field model, am I right? I was referring to section IIA of the reference I provided, i.e. solving this model with the JW transform as you mentioned before (you said eigenvalues are easy not eigenvectors though). I guess that in 1D the only possible options are a circle (periodic) or a line (not periodic). I can also hint from you last response that "exactly solvable" is not well defined? Mainly because of the "mumble something unheardable".

"Onsager's solution is for the case where there is no magnetic field, so it would not include the transverse field model, am I right?" Transverse field is different story. One do not need field term in solution. "last response that "exactly solvable" is not well defined?" Problem is that in spin system most for eve them where there is progress progess is not that there is a total solution. Only partial solution at best.

I see that full solution may be hard. What do you mean by "One do not need field term in solution."? and recapping a bit, transverse field Ising model in 1D has easy eigenvalues (and ground state) by JW but not eigenstates, right?

"What do you mean by "One do not need field term in solution."? and recapping a bit, transverse field Ising model in 1D has easy eigenvalues (and ground state) by JW but not eigenstates, right? ": Suzuki-Trotter formalism transfers 1D Ising with transverse field to 2D Ising model with exact solution. If 1D transverse Ising model do not have periodic boundary conditions then there is no exact solution.

I do not see how the Suzuki-Trotter formula would transform the transverse field Ising model in 1D to a Ising model (without a transverse field) in 2D. Why does the absence of periodic boundary break its solvability? and again, what does exact solution mean in your last question: full diagonalization, knowing eigenvalues, knowing GS but not other eigenstates? In this sense, where have you find those things (references)?
